# ERC20 tokens in Metamask suddenly not showing

Tags: tokens, erc-20, metamask

I've been using **Metamask** in Chrome for a while and had a list of ERC20 tokens in Ropsten network already added in the Assets section through their contract addresses:

- DAI address: 0xad6d458402f60fd3bd25163575031acdce07538d
- UNI address: 0x1f9840a85d5af5bf1d1762f925bdaddc4201f984
- WETH address: 0xc778417e063141139fce010982780140aa0cd5ab

In fact, when connected to Uniswap, I can see all balances with the right amounts.

However, all these tokens have suddenly disappeared from Metamask and now I can only see ETH. If I try to manually add those tokens again (Add Token -> Custom Token -> Token Contract Address), I receive the following message:

> Token has already been added.

Even after reopening Chrome or changing networks, I can't see the tokens.

Any alternative before uninstalling Metamask and importing the accounts again?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I also noticed that when trying to connect to Remix IDE, I was not able to set the `Injected Web3` method. It seems that Metamask came into an unstable state, so I finally had to reinstall it.

Ensure to have your mnemonic phrase before!